# Blazor modal dialog has not focus

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor, keyevent

I have a custom dialog in Blazor. It basically works fine but has some flaws:

1. When tabbing with keyboard focus jumps between controls on underlying page and not inside dialog.
2. When clicking <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard the keydown event is not triggered.

What is missing?

```
<div class="custom-modal-overlay fade @showClass" style="@style" aria-modal="@Show" aria-hidden="@(!Show)" aria-labelledby="Dialog" @onclick="HandleCancel" @onkeydown="OverlayKeyDown">
    <div class="custom-modal-dialog" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        <div class="custom-modal-header">
            <h1>@Title</h1>
            @if (!ShowCancel)
            {
                <div class="cancel-icon" @onclick="HandleCancel">
                    <span class="material-icons-outlined cancel-icon" role="img" aria-label="Cancel">clear</span>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="custom-modal-content">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
        <div class="custom-modal-footer">
            @if (ShowCancel)
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" @onclick="HandleCancel">Cancel</button>
            }
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick="HandleConfirm">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowCancel { get; set; } = true;


    [Parameter]
    public bool Show { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ShowChanged { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnCancel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnConfirm { get; set; }



    private string showClass => Show ? "show" : string.Empty;
    private string style => Show ? "display: block;" : "display: none;";


    private void OverlayKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Detect what key is hit and take proper action
        var key = e.Key;

        Show = false;
        ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(Show);
        OnCancel.InvokeAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void HandleCancel()
    {
        Show = false;
        ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(Show);
        OnCancel.InvokeAsync();
    }

    private void HandleConfirm()
    {
        Show = false;
        ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(Show);
        OnConfirm.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add tabindex="-1" to the root element where you have onkeydown. Add ref directive to the element and call elementReference.FocusAsync()

Comment: Great answer! That solved the most important part with the Enter and Esacpe keys. But the tabindex still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help out future readers I here add the full code with suggested changes from Liero. Note the added overlayElement and that the proposed call to `InvokeFocus` needs to be done in `OnAfterRender` event handler.

This solves the `Enter` and `Escape` requirement but as far as I understand the tab issue is still the same.

```
<div class="custom-modal-overlay fade @showClass" style="@style" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="@Show" aria-hidden="@(!Show)" aria-labelledby="Dialog" @onclick="HandleCancel" @onkeydown="OverlayKeyDown" @ref="overlayElement">
    <div class="custom-modal-dialog" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        <div class="custom-modal-header">
            <h1>@Title</h1>
            @if (!ShowCancel)
            {
                <div class="cancel-icon" @onclick="HandleCancel">
                    <span class="material-icons-outlined cancel-icon" role="img" aria-label="Cancel">clear</span>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="custom-modal-content">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
        <div class="custom-modal-footer">
            @if (ShowCancel)
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" @onclick="HandleCancel">Cancel</button>
            }
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @onclick="HandleConfirm">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowCancel { get; set; } = true;


    [Parameter]
    public bool Show { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ShowChanged { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }


    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnCancel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnConfirm { get; set; }


    private ElementReference overlayElement;
    private string showClass => Show ? "show" : string.Empty;
    private string style => Show ? "display: block;" : "display: none;";

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        overlayElement.FocusAsync();
    }

    private void OverlayKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case "Escape":
                HandleCancel();
                break;
            case "Enter":
                HandleConfirm();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void HandleCancel()
    {
        Show = false;
        ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(Show);
        OnCancel.InvokeAsync();
    }

    private void HandleConfirm()
    {
        Show = false;
        ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(Show);
        OnConfirm.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Preventing tabbing outside the modal is an interesting problem.  The solution usually involves using JavaScript to trap user input. If you scroll to the bottom of this page there is  example code and a demo on how to limit tabs to a modal dialog. See: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex